# How to get index value as an id to div?

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I am using Angular 2.0. I have an array called `addExtra: number[] = [0,1,2,3];`.

My HTML code is as follows:

```html
<div *ngFor="let val of addExtra">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin-left:15px;">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"
            (click)='delete(val)'>
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <label for="isCheckBox">Draw</label>
            <input id="isCheckBox" id=val type="checkbox" class="setCheckbox" (change)="isChecked($event)" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the val meaning 0, 1, 2, 3 as id to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="{{val}}" type="checkbox" class="setCheckbox" (change)="isChecked($event)" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let val of addExtra; let i = index;">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="margin-left:15px;">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"
                (click)='delete(val)'>
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <label for="isCheckBox">Draw</label>
                <input id="isCheckBox" id={{i}} type="checkbox" class="setCheckbox" (change)="isChecked($event)" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 id for a html tag.

```
<input id={{val}} type="checkbox" class="setCheckbox" (change)="isChecked($event)" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" />
```